# Can Arduino Uno send data to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: arduino, google-cloud-firestore, iot

I need information on how to connect and send data to firestore from an Arduino Board  and an ESP2866 module. I've only found tutorials using Firebase realtime, the ones I found using Firestore are using the NodeMCU board.

I have a Vue.js application reading some fields from a Firestore db, which should recieve information from the arduino with some attached sensors. From what I've seen my options are changing to firebase realtime or changing to NodeMCU( not possible ). I some direction to follow, on how to use firestore with arduino or just change the db.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to have an online server, after that it becomes very easy. Send your Arduino data to the server and then write the data to Cloud Firestore.
To find how to write data into Firestore, refer this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data and chose the integration for your server. Firestore supports most of the popular server integrations like Node.js, GO, PHP, Python etc.

As answered by @doublejosh, refer to this documentation: [firebase-extended](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

I had quick success using [firebase-arduino](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino) for the real-time database rather than Firestore. Since Arduino projects are generally hobby, this should probably work well enough.